# QField connected to Cloud

Tags: qgis, qfield, cloud-gis

My question is if it would be possible somehow to upload the data taken in the field using QFIELD in the cloud. I would like to know if there is any similar workflow as with, for example in ArcGIS, Collector/Survey123 upgrading the data directly into an ArcGIS Online.

I have seen they are going to release something called QFIELDCLOUD, so will this approach be similar to ArcGIS Online?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[qfield.cloud](https://qfield.cloud) is exactly what you're looking for. It is natively supported in QField and allows you to synchronise your field survey directly to the cloud (and to your team) as soon as you have connectivity. This way you can work with no issues wherever you need to.

Once synchronised, you can use your data with QGIS, or any other tools you wish. Later we'll also add the possibility to directly publish your data on a web map from the QFieldCloud web panel.

We are currently in beta and are opening up spots every day to new preregistered users. If you preregister on [qfield.cloud](https://qfield.cloud) you'll get an information mail very soon, and if you reach out directly to us at [opengis.ch](https://opengis.ch) you might even get an immediate invitation ;)

you can also checkout my [1h] talk about it on QGIS's [youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h58EzJR7XwI)

Disclaimer: I'm one of the developers of QField/QFieldCloud

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Really appreciate it! I have already register myself into QFIELDCLOUD long time ago.. But I never got an answer and I wasn't sure about the functionalities either, so I guess I just have to keep being patience and have a look at the video you posted in the meantime. Looking forward to start testing this way of working :)

Comment: @Serggg182 we are opening up all the waiting list accounts currently, we had a huge interest. if you were not enabled yet, you can contact me (marco@opengis.ch) and I'll invite you :)

Answer (score 5):

You can try https://inputapp.io which is based on QGIS and comes with a cloud synchronisation service called Mergin (https://public.cloudmergin.com).

Data from same QGIS project can be downloaded on multiple devices. Each user can then collect data (offline if needed). When users sync data, it will be consolidated through the service.

You can also use Mergin with QField. But you will need the Input app for handling the synchronisation.

Disclaimer: we are developers of the app and the service.